# How to use ManagedExecutorService with Jaxrs 2.1 AsyncResponse in Java EE 8/Glassfish v5?

Tags: jakarta-ee, java-8, glassfish, jax-rs, reactive

I am experiencing the new features provided in Jaxrs 2.1, eg reactive client, completionstage support etc, I am using Java EE8/Glassfish v5 RELEASE.

The following sample code worked well in [my sample codes for Java EE7/Wildfly 10](https://github.com/hantsy/angularjs-ee7-sample/blob/master/cdi/src/main/java/com/hantsylab/example/ee7/blog/api/AsyncResource.java), but the request is blocked and timed out in Java EE8/Glassfish v5.

```
@Path("async")
@Stateless
public class AsyncResource {

@Resource
private ManagedExecutorService executor;

@Inject
Logger LOG;

@GET
public void getAsync(final @Suspended AsyncResponse res) {
    res.setTimeoutHandler(
            (ar) -> {
                ar.resume(Response.status(Response.Status.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE)
                        .entity("Operation timed out --- please try again.").build());
            }
    );
    res.setTimeout(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    executor.submit(() -> {
        //do long run operations.
        try {
            LOG.log(Level.INFO, " execute long run task in AsyncResource");
            //Thread.sleep(new Random().nextInt(1005));
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "error :" + ex.getMessage());
        }
        res.resume(Response.ok("asynchronous resource").build());
    });
}

}
```

Another sample when I tried the `CompletionStage`:

```
@Path("cs")
@Stateless
public class CompletionStageResource {

@Resource
private ManagedExecutorService executor;

@Inject
Logger LOG;

@GET
public CompletionStage<String> getAsync() {
    CompletionStage<String> cs = CompletableFuture
            .<String>supplyAsync(
                    () -> {
                        try {
                            LOG.log(Level.INFO, " execute long run task in CompletionStageResource");
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                            LOG.log(Level.SEVERE, "error :" +ex.getMessage());
                        }
                        return "return CompletableFuture instead of @Suspended";
                    }
                   // , executor
            );

    return cs;
}

}
```

In the above codes, I commented out the executor, if I used executor, got blocked as the first sample.

Anyone have the similar issue here? How to solve this problem?